# SherlcokFargments Button in one fragment to call second fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to figure out how fragments are working. 
I have 3 classes, MainActivity, Fragment1 and Fragment2.

MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
and

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Fragment1 firstFragment = new Fragment1();
    firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container1, firstFragment).commit();
```

Now, I load Fragment1 into my fragment_container, and it displays nice.

(So main_activity.xml has only one )

Ok, Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment, does nothing more then

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1layout, container, false);
```

So I just inflate it from my .xml that has one text view and one button.

Where in the world now can I instance Button, and give him code to replace Fragment1 with Fragment2?

What is the code for that, as I'm now "in Fragment1" so I need to somehow communicate with Fragment holder and tell it "replace me with Fragment2".

Fragment2 also extends SherlockFragment, and does nothing, inflates it's empty .xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your fragment2 from fragment1 like below

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1layout, container, false);
            Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Replace your fragment

                }
            });
        return view;
}
```

Comment: You are bless :) I tried without view.findViewBy ... and then it does not work. Thank you! This helped a lot to understand at least a bit, but what I need is 2 fragments on same "view" ..

Answer (score 0):

> I'm now "in Fragment1" so I need to somehow communicate with Fragment holder and tell it "replace me with Fragment2".

If you want replace Fragment1 to Fragment2 when you click on button which is into Fragment1:

(best practices)

1. you should create callbacks from fragment1 to MainActivity like it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)
2. into MainActivity place logics which will replace fragment1 to fragment2.

(bad practices)

1. Create method into `MainActivity` which will replace one fragment to another for example `changeFirstFragmentToAnother()`
2. then when you need to change fragment1 to fragment2 you may call this method manually (from fragment1) like this:

   `((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeFirstFragmentToAnother();`